# How to make install Chrome extension for Firefox

Tags: gmail, firefox-extensions, text-formatting

I read with great relief that I can add strikethrough formatting to Gmail with the add-on described [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69761/89343)—the description says it works with Chrome *and Firefox*. But the link in that post takes me to the Chrome store, where I'm told to use Chrome. I already do, but prefer Firefox. Once I've installed the add-on to Chrome, how can I get it in Firefox? Many thanks to any and all who can enlighten me.

Comment: Questions about browsers and add-ons are off-topic here. Try [su].

Answer (score 0):

you may have some luck looking in the firefox extensions store...
Go to this website in firefox:
"about:addons"
Then on the right select get addons.
Now in the top right you can search for what you want :)
Hope I helped